# Combobox value is not adding to the database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-express

My code is not adding a combobox value to the database. What might be the problem here?

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=CEX-PC\SQLEXPRESS;"
                              + "Initial Catalog=inventorydatabase;"
                              + "Integrated Security=True";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    con.Open();
    string query
        = "INSERT INTO userdetail (username, password, position) VALUES ('"
        + username.Text + "', '" + password.Text + "', '"
        + position.SelectedValue + "' )";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Is the name and password inserted?

Comment: Windows or Web Application

Comment: @Bart Friederichs yes

Comment: @Steve no error message

Comment: any wrong with my code?

Comment: what is the content of `query` variable in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

If its web application consider this:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=CEX-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial     
                     Catalog=inventorydatabase;Integrated Security=True";
                     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

con.Open();
string query = "INSERT INTO userdetail (username, password, position) VALUES(@username,@password,@val )";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

command.CommandType= CommandType.Text;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",txt1.text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",txt2.text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val",ddl.SelectedItem.Value);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Comment: I'd suggest including a `using(SqlConnection con = new ...){ con.Open(); ... }` instead of the close. This will ensure that if an exception occurs it get's disposed properly.

Comment: Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)// i change the code like above now showing error

Comment: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", position.SelectedItem.Value);

Comment: have you tried this?

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", position.Items[position.SelectedIndex].Value);